# Passing JSON Objects as Parameters to a Directive's Link Function

Tags: angularjs

In a directive (let's call it **basket**), I have a JSON object (let's call it **fruit**) that is available locally (i.e. no need for $http). The **fruit** JSON object is fairly complex and has dynamic data in it each time.

The directive is also dynamically generating some html elements that each have their own directives (**apple** and **banana**), and then compiling these new elements into the page:

```
myApp.directive("basket", function($compile) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element) {

        var html = '';

        var fruits = ['apple', 'banana'];
        for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
          var fruit = {
            name: fruits[i],
            /* ... plus many other complex properties/objects/arrays ... */
          };
          html += '<div ' + fruits[i] + '=""></div>';
        }

        // Compile element.
        var linkFn = $compile(html);
        var content = linkFn(scope);
        element.append(content);

      }
    };
});
```

The resulting html would look something like this:

```
<div basket="">
  <div apple="">...</div>
  <div banana="">...</div>
</div>
```

How can I get the **fruit** JSON object passed into the **apple** and **banana** directive link functions as a parameter?

For example, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
myApp.directive("apple", function($compile) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, fruit) {

        // Build some custom html about an apple...
        var html = fruit.name;
        html += other_apple_related_stuff(fruit);

        // Compile element.
        var linkFn = $compile(html);
        var content = linkFn($scope);
        $element.append(content);

      }
    };
});

myApp.directive("banana", function($compile) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, fruit) {

        // Build some custom html about an banana...
        var html = fruit.name;
        html += other_banana_related_stuff(fruit);

        // Compile element.
        var linkFn = $compile(html);
        var content = linkFn($scope);
        $element.append(content);

      }
    };
});
```

Although the **apple** and **banana** directives are similar, they are different enough that I'd like to separate their implementations across multiple files.

I understand I can place the **fruit** JSON object in the *$scope*, and then pull it out later in the **apple** and **banana** directives.

But I'd really like to have this large **fruit** JSON object be shipped into a each directive's link function as a parameter.

**SOLVED**

Thanks to @AWolf's demo code, I was able to fork the code and get the desired output: https://jsfiddle.net/tyler_frankenstein/7cyLgscj/2/

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood it correclty. You could use a service and inject it into every directive.
Then you can use the same JSON in every directive.

Please have a look at the demo below and in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/7cyLgscj/).

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .factory('fruitService', fruits)
    .directive('basket', basket)
    .directive('banana', banana)
    .directive('apple', apple);

function basket($compile, fruitService) {
    var ddo = {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var html = '';

            var fruits = ['apple', 'banana'];
            
            for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
                var fruit = {
                    name: fruits[i],
                    /* ... plus many other complex properties/objects/arrays ... */
                };
                fruitService.pushFruits(fruit);
                html += '<div ' + fruits[i] + '=""></div>';
            }

            // Compile element.
            var linkFn = $compile(html);
            var content = linkFn(scope);
            element.append(content);
        }
    };

    return ddo;
}

basket.$inject = ['$compile', 'fruitService'];

function banana(fruitService) {
    return {
        template: '<p>banana</p><pre>{{fruits|json}}</pre>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('banana', fruitService.getFruits());
            scope.fruits = fruitService.getFruits();
        }
    };
}

banana.$inject = ['fruitService'];

function apple(fruitService) {
    return {
        template: '<p>apple</p><pre>{{ctrl.fruits|json}}</pre>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            // could be also the link method
            console.log('apple', fruitService.getFruits());
            this.fruits = fruitService.getFruits();
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    };
}

apple.$inject = ['fruitService'];

function fruits() {
    return {
        fruits: [],
        pushFruits: function (newFruits) {
            this.fruits.push(newFruits);
        },
        getFruits: function () {
            return this.fruits;
        }
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <basket></basket>
</div>
```